# Does Windows Small Business Server 2011 With IIS 7.5 Support The FTP Service 7.5?

Tags: windows, ftp

I have tried to get the FTP Service 7.5 installed using genuine Microsoft setup files on a Windows 2011 SBS machine that's already running IIS 7.5, but none of these links below have worked--neither 32 nor 64-bit--due to a claim that these FTP services are only compatible with Windows 2008:

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=143196
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=143197

The error message states, "This version of the operating system is not supported. FTP Service 7.5 for IIS 7.0 can only be installed on Windows Server 2008."

[image]

I suppose I could go with a third-party solution but it seems to me Microsoft couldn't have left this feature out like that. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that just because the IIS version is 7.5 it doesn't mean that the similarly numbered version 7.5 of the FTP Service is compatible. Instead of attempting to install it in the manner I tried originally, I had to open the Server Manager and scroll down to the "Web Server (IIS)" section:

[image]

On the right side of that section, next to the Role Services listbox, I then clicked Add Role Services. On the pop-up that appeared, I scrolled towards the bottom and found the missing, as-yet-not-installed FTP Service!

[image]

I simply checked the box next to FTP Service and then clicked Install. Finally, to complete the setup, I followed the instructions at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/creating-a-new-ftp-site-in-iis-7 to create a working, receptive FTP site. Voila!